# Add foreign key index Loopback 4 MySQL

Tags: mysql, loopback4

i am new in Loopback 4

I followed [this tutorial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/todo-list-tutorial.html) to get started and everything worked fine.

I tried to create my own models Category and SubCategory using a MySQL database, with one to many relation (one category has many sub categories), i have noticed that it did create a field in subcategory table (categoryId) but the foreign key index is missing.

can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

LoopBack 4 does not implicitly add foreign key constraints. This is to allow weak cross-datasource relations (e.g. a relation between PostgreSQL & Oracle).

Hence, the responsibility falls on the connectors to provide an interface to define these constraints. This however, means that there isn't a consistent interface across different connectors. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2331) to track this.

In the case of MySQL:

```js
 @model({
  settings: {
    foreignKeys: {
      categorySubCategoryFK: {
        name: 'categorySubCategoryFK',
        entity: 'Category',
        entityKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'categoryId',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

In case auto-migration is used (which it should not be used in production!), `migrate.ts` would need to be updated to define explicit ordering of the schemas:

```js
await app.migrateSchema({
  existingSchema,
  models: ['Category', 'SubCategory'],
});
```

### Further reading

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/todo-list-tutorial-sqldb.html#specify-the-foreign-key-constraints-in-todo-model
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/MySQL-connector.html

Answer (score 0):

found the answer [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/todo-list-tutorial-sqldb.html#specify-the-foreign-key-constraints-in-todo-model), besides adding the settings to `@model` annotation, like so

```
 @model({
    settings: {
    foreignKeys: {
      categorySubCategoryFK: {
        name: 'categorySubCategoryFK',
        entity: 'Category',
        entityKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'categoryId',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

you have to change to specify in which order tables should be created in `migrate.ts` and change this

```
await app.migrateSchema({existingSchema});
```

to this

```
await app.migrateSchema({
    existingSchema,
    models: ['Category', 'SubCategory'],
  });
```

more details [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/todo-list-tutorial-sqldb.html#specify-the-foreign-key-constraints-in-todo-model)

Answer (score -1):

Loopback 4 creates relation on models and Api's not on database. Thus it won't get reflected on your mysql database